# Automate Ajax Applications with Selenium

Tags: ajax, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I am trying to automate an Ajax application using Selenium WebDriver. Selenese commands mention in the selenium documents not working well with the application. Is there any better approach or commands to deal with Ajax applications? Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Comment: waits are great for ajax. You can be more specific in what issue you're facing with while automating

Comment: I am trying to automate JIRA kind of website where Ajax is used heavily.It is just a kind of estimation to select the technology. what do you thing is it possible to automate such a website with selenium ?

Comment: You can automate a website with a lot of Ajax. You need to get familiar with ExpectedConditions and WebDriver waits. Because Ajax is dynamic and timing is variable you need to learn how to use and configure wait times for elements to appear and disappear. It would be much better if you asked about a specific item you are trying to automate tests for and a specific problem you're having with it. Posting source code is also far more helpful than a question that is vague and easily answered by googling 'Ajax' and 'Selenium'.

Comment: ok thanks Selena, I will try with WebDriver wait commands..

Answer (score 1):

Important thing about Ajax applications is whether Jquery is active or not. If it is active then script need to wait for it. You can handle it with following code.

```
while (true) // Handle the timeout
    {
        boolean ajaxIsComplete = (boolean)((JavascriptExecutor) wbDv).executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
        if (ajaxIsComplete)
            break;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Tell me if it is helpful or not.
Thanks